# Lambda Select Columns Without an Expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I want an EF query to return an entire column, but I want to choose that column with a variable. Can that be done? I.E. use a variable instead of a lambda expression as such:

```
FieldValues = db.PbiData
  .Where(x => DatasetList.Contains(x.DatasetId))
  .Select(FieldName)
  .ToList()
```

FieldName will always match one of the column names of the PbiData table. For example, the first FieldName value is "Department", and the query below works just fine:

```
FieldValues = db.PbiData
  .Where(x => DatasetList.Contains(x.DatasetId))
  .Select(x=>x.Department)
  .ToList()
```

The where clause in each of these queries simply restricts the data returned to the data relevant to the current user.

My attempt, per a comment below:

```
    foreach(var F in model.FieldMetaData)
    {

        if (F.FieldType == "String")
        {
            PbiFieldData PbiFieldData = new PbiFieldData()
            {
                FieldName = F.FieldName,
                FieldValues = await db.PbiData.Where(x => DatasetList.Contains(x.DatasetId)).Select(F.FieldName).ToListAsync()
        };

            model.PbiData.Add(PbiFieldData);
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use Expression

```
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Table), yourVariable);
MemberExpression propExpression = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, yourVariable);
Expression<Func<Table, string>> selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<Table, string>>(propExpression, param);
var result = db.Table.Select(selector).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [System.Linq.Dynamic](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) Nuget for the purpose

```
var fieldName = "Department";
var results = context.PbiData
                     .Where(x=> DatasetList.Contains(x.DatasetId))
                     .Select(fieldName);
```

Based on comment, to convert to List, one can use

```
var results = await context.PbiData
                     .Where(x=> DatasetList.Contains(x.DatasetId))
                     .Select(fieldName).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I don't think this is quite what I need. As stated, the column name in the select list will be a variable, not a string.

Comment: @extensionhelp when you say variable . do you mean , a string variable which has columnname ? say columnName = "Department" ? or ?

Comment: @extensionhelp if that's the case, as explained in OP, please check updated answer

Comment: That didn’t produce an error, but when I added ToList() to the end, it did. Any idea why?

Comment: You could use .ToListAsync().

Comment: The error is a NullReferenceException on `model.PbiData.Add(PbiFieldData);` ... I've updated the full code in OP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186510/discussion-between-anu-viswan-and-extensionhelp).

Answer (score 0):

You can write native sql query:

```
var FieldValues = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<string>
(
$@"select {fieldName} from PbiData 
where DatasetId in ({string.Join(", ", DatasetList.Select(x => $"'{x}'"))})"
).ToList();
```

Comment: No luck. This one immediately produces an error on the first @ symbol "Keyword, identifier, or string expected after verbatim specifier @"

Comment: I'm getting the error `Invalid pseudocolumn "$abffc3b5".` ... I should have mentioned, the DatasetList and the DatasetIds are GUIDs, so maybe they need to be treated differently.

Comment: To clarify, the string "abffc3b5" is part of the GUID of the first dataset.